# magento2 checkout summary page refresh on click redio button event

Tags: magento2, jquery, knockoutjs, checkout-page

I want apply different charges with customer group on-click radio button via ajax summary part refresh in checkout page.If anyone know reply me.

Comment: Add your code that you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was tested and verified ajax, data update and get without page refresh, its working from side via below code.

```
var deferred = $.Deferred();
getTotalsAction([], deferred);
```